SQL Server left join to a view has different IO than the "same" inline left join
Left joining to a view produces higher IO than inlining the same left joins written directly into the outer query.
Below is a minimal example, executed on On SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU14) (KB5038325) - 16.0.4135.4 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit)
What is notable to me is the logical reads for tables R1 and R2 in query "A".
Included for interest are two additional similar queries, C and D, with the same logical IO as B.
Plans for the 4 queries are here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJd0qgHRR
I have seen the same pattern of IO results on multiple SQL Server instances, from 2016 to 2022, running both on laptops and Azure L32s vm's.
Can anyone explain SQL Server's choice here? Why does the query optimizer treat the view so differently from an identical inline query?
If there was a windowing function or similar inside the view, then I would understand the need for the engine to "evaluate the whole view" before joining the result into the outer query. But here it seems to me that the optimizer "should" be able to produce identical plans.
In-depth explanations would be welcome (if warranted).
set nocount on;
set statistics io, xml off;

drop table if exists L, R1, R2, R3;

create table L (i int primary key clustered, c char(100));
create table R1 (i int primary key clustered, c1 char(100), j int);
create table R2 (j int primary key clustered, c2 char(100), k int);
create table R3 (k int primary key clustered, c3 char(100));
go

insert      R1
select      top 100000 row_number() over (order by o1.object_id), 'c', checksum(newid())
from        sys.all_objects o1
cross join  sys.all_objects o2;

insert   R2
select   top 10000 j, 'c1', checksum(newid())
from     R1
order by newid();

insert   R3
select   top 5000 k, 'c2'
from     R2
order by newid();

insert   L 
select   top 1000 i, 'c3' 
from     R1 
order by newid();
go

create or alter view V as 
   select      i, c1, c2, c3
   from        R1
   left join   R2 on R2.j = R1.j  -- inner join here makes no difference
   left join   R3 on R3.k = R2.k; -- inner join here makes no difference
go

set statistics io, xml on;

print 'A-------------------------';

select      c1, c2, c3
from        L
left join   V on V.i = L.i;

print 'B-------------------------';

select      c1, c2, c3
from        L
left join   R1 on R1.i = L.i
left join   R2 on R2.j = R1.j
left join   R3 on R3.k = R2.k;

print 'C-------------------------';

select      c1, c2, c3
from        L
join        R1 on R1.i = L.i
left join   R2 on R2.j = R1.j
left join   R3 on R3.k = R2.k;

print 'D-------------------------';

select      c1, c2, c3
from        L
join        V on V.i = L.i;

The output (truncated) is as follows:
A-------------------------
Table 'R3'. Scan count 0, logical reads 192
Table 'R2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2000 <<<< ?
Table 'R1'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3000 <<<< ?
Table 'L'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17
B-------------------------
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 
Table 'L'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17
Table 'R1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1457
Table 'R2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 147
Table 'R3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 73
C-------------------------
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 
Table 'L'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17, phys
Table 'R1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1457
Table 'R2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 147
Table 'R3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 73
D-------------------------
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 
Table 'L'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17
Table 'R1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1457
Table 'R2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 147
Table 'R3'. Scan count 1, logical reads 73


A more accurate inlining is this https://dbfiddle.uk/6l0MdOAL - which also gives the 2K/3K reads - on my PC that plan with the nested loops executes quicker than the one with the sorts and merge joins anyway (though the merge join plan is given a cost of around 50% of the nested loops plan so is cheaper per SQL Server's cost model)

Thanks @MartinSmith. The actual execution times are fairly similar, in my tests sometimes one would be faster, sometimes the other. I think it's probably also noteworthy that the page reads are exactly 2000/3000 in this case, and in the original ("real") scenario where I first saw this, the page reads were 4000 each for multiple tables involved in the view. Exact multiples of 1000 seem suspicious to me. It also seems to me that the "nested" left join in your fiddle is logically equivalent to the non-nested joins. I am still intrigued by these results.

It does just look like it doesn't have logic to produce the left deep tree LOJ(LOJ(LOJ (L,R1),R2),R3) from the bushy tree LOJ(L,LOJ(LOJ(R1,R2),R3)) as trying to force the plan fails https://dbfiddle.uk/9xPpsr8C

Indeed. Unfortunate - in the "real" scenario the view involves more data and more tables, and the left join to the view creates a more pronounced cost difference, but would otherwise be valuable as a reusable fragment in multiple different parts of the solution. Not an unusual situation when working with SQL, but in my particular scenario here is a slightly more painful example than usual that I was hoping to work around. Cheers.
